# mysqli_query prints <br/> without reason?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new to PHP programming and i try to learn how to work with databases. I have MySQL ready, with 1 database, containing 1 table which contains 7 entries.
The problem is that when i try to output the entries to a very simple table, before the creation of the table it output 7 times < BR /> without reason.
The code is like this:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","**********", "*****");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}  else { echo "Connection was OK! <br/>";}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM pelates") or die(mysql_error());
echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>ID</th><th>Onoma</th><th>Epwnymo</th><th>Hlikia</th><th>Genethlia</th></tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr> <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td> <td>" . $row['name'] . "</td> <td>" . $row['surname'] . "</td> <td>" . $row['age'] . "</td> <td>" . $row['birthday'] . "</td></tr>";
echo "<br>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Everything i believe looks good. Here is part of the output:

```
Connection was OK! <br/><table border='1'><tr><th>ID</th><th>Onoma</th>
```

As you can see the is only 1 < br /> between the message "Connection was OK" and the table. In real it produce another 7! Here is the result of inspect element in Chrome (same as Firefox too!):

```
Connection was OK! 
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<table border='1'><tr><th>
```

As i understand, when i define:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM pelates") or die(mysql_error());
```

It takes 7 results into "memory", but this is supposed to not printed in real. Why it prints 7 breakrows, while i didn't told it to? And what can i do to prevent it?

Thank you very much for your time, and sorry for the long post.

Comment: What's the output if you view source (Not inspect element)?

Comment: You probably want to change your database password...

Comment: Four votes to stupid *localized* & stupid question while negative votes to correct answer. Faint.

Comment: @Rikesh If you believe the downvotes are incorrect, feel free to counter them. I won't vote for the downvoted posts, rather I'll upvote the answer that actually _explains_ what's going on here.

Comment: @Rikesh on the other hand, the correct answer could have been a little bit more explained, as it is now after being edited. The question is not too localized, imho. (btw, i didn't downvote anything)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put `<br>` **between** rows in table `</tr><br/><tr>.` As you mentioned *inspect element* both in FF and Chrome shows them before table. It's because `<br>` doesn't belong there and browser has to put it somewhere so it puts them before table.

If you would display source (instead of inspecting elements), you'd get correct result.

Comment: I was just about to post this. The <br/> can only be inside the <table> if it is inside a table cell such as <td>. Otherwise the browser will move it outside the table for you.

Comment: Thank you so much! Crystal clear explanation! :)

Answer (score 1):

Its all because of this line

```
echo "<br>";
```

Remove it.

The reason is because you haven't putted `<br/>` inside `<td></td>` tags. So it comes before `<table>`.

[Codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/JsfXc2)

Comment: Nope! Read the question again. He is getting `<br/>`s before the `<table>. The line of code you are pointing comes after it (and for every row).

Comment: @Thrustmaster http://codepad.viper-7.com/JsfXc2 see this :)

Comment: @Thrustmaster: http://jsfiddle.net/UY7z6/

Comment: Any reason for downvote?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Thrustmaster put here an explanation

Comment: @All: I downvoted it. I'll take it back. Vyktor's answer makes sense, and so does the link in the answer. :)

Answer (score -1):

Remove `echo "<br>";` inside while loop